# Get file names while displaying and before uploading on server using html and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am selecting multiple images using html tag 'input file multiple html' as below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", 
new {@id = "filesToUploadID", @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
<div class="col-md-10" id="selectedFiles"></div>
```

Then in javascript, I attached 'onchange' event listner to the above tag. When I select multiple images, I get all the attached images to the tag using jquery. But I need image file names as well. While getting image file names, I get only one file name poplulated in my html along with image using jquery.
jquery/ javascript is below

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
function init() {
    document.querySelector('#filesToUploadID').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
}

function handleFileSelect(e) {
    debugger;
    NameArray = [];
    if (!e.target.files) return;
    selDiv.innerHTML = "";
    var files = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        NameArray.push(f.name);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var html = "<img src='" + e.target.result + "' />";// + "<div>" +  + "</div>";//+ "<br clear=\"left\"/>";
            $(selDiv).append($(html));
            //selDiv.innerHTML += html;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

I tool help from this [link](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/09/10/Adding-a-file-display-list-to-a-multifile-upload-HTML-control) and implemented both ways but could not succeed.

All images names are relevant to the images. What I am getting is like this
[image]
It's source code is 
[image]

I have to assign id's based on image names that's why it is important to get relevant image names. Any lead to the topic will be high appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any outputting of the name ...?

Comment: @Stuart, I actual line is as below
var html = "<img src='" + e.target.result + "' />" + "<div>" + f.name + "</div>";

Answer (score 0):

var f = files[i];
var fileName = e.target.f.name